# How to convert clob to string with encoding in java

Tags: java, unicode, apache-commons-io

We are doing massive batch of xml processing and the logic to convert clob to string is shown below.

```
import java.sql.Clob
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

String extractXml(Clob xmlClob) {

    log.info "DefaultCharset: " + groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.getDefaultSystemCharset()

    String sourceXml
    try {
        sourceXml = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(xmlClob?.getCharacterStream()), encoding)            // 1. Encoding not working
        sourceXml = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(xmlClob?.getCharacterStream(), encoding), encoding)  // 2. Encoding working
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }

    return sourceXml
}
```

My queries:

a. I am not sure why (1) doesn't work even though I am using getCharacterStream() instead of getAsciiStream(). 
    but (2) seems to work fine may be I am using explicit overriding of system encoding ?

b. The solution (2) looks bit odd as you are specifing 2 times the encoding format (one for bytes array and one for string creation).
   I am not sure if there are any performance issues or wondered if there are better ways to write them?

c. I thought of not using the Apache-commons libraries and use a simple java package solution.
   But the suprising thing is, I did not give any explicit encoding but it seems to work perfectly.
   Is it because It does "streams character -> straight to string buffering" ?

```
/*
 * working perfectly and retuns encoding correctly
 */
String extractXmlWithoutApacheCommons(Clob xmlClob) {

    log.info "DefaultCharset: " + groovy.util.CharsetToolkit.getDefaultSystemCharset()

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer((int) xmlClob.length())
    try {
        Reader r = xmlClob.getCharacterStream()
        char[] cbuf = new char[2048]
        int n = 0

        while ((n = r.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length)) != -1) {
            if (n > 0) {
                sb.append(cbuf, 0, n)
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }

    return sb.toString()
}
```

Can you guys please shed some light to understand them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Clob` already has an encoding. It's whatever you've specified in the database, and once you read it on Java side it'll be a `String` (with the implicit UTF-16 encoding, not that it matters at all).

Whatever you think you're doing with all those encoding tricks is wrong and useless. You only need to specify an encoding when turning `bytes` to `chars` or the other way around. You're dealing with `chars` only (except in your first example where you for some unknown reason want to turn them to bytes).

If you want to use `IOUtils`, then `readFully(Reader input, char[] buffer)` would be the method to use.

The platform default encoding has no effect in this whole question, since you shouldn't be working with bytes at all.

Edit:
A *slightly* more modern way with the standard JDK classes would be to use `Reader.read(CharBuffer target)` like

```
CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate((int) xmlClob.length());
while(r.read(cb) != -1)
    ;
return cb.toString();
```

but it doesn't really make a huge difference (it's a bit nicer looking).

Comment: Thanks.. I understand more of when to use encoding and also that it is unnecessary to convert them to bytes when you are already dealing with character streams. Is the second example a good one where I use java standard library only ?

Comment: Yea it looks good. There's probably a more "modern" way to do it, but there's nothing wrong with reading into a `StringBuffer` in a loop like that.